# How to properly use subprocess.Popen thread's in python?

Tags: python, stdin, popen

I am writing a python script which will execute some another script from `bash` terminals. I need `two  bash terminal` and execute some script in that bash terminal one by one. After executing the script, I will read the out put messages to a `Tkinter text area`. I have designed simple python script which will create `2 process`. I am using `thread` to monitor the stdout and stderror for each processes. I am using while loop to hold the process.

**Here is the my script**

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
import threading

class TKValidator:
    def __init__(self): 
        #create TK
        self.ws = Tk()
        self.ws.state('zoomed')
        
        self.flag = IntVar()
        
        #process for bash 1
        self.process1 = subprocess.Popen(["bash"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        #process for bash 2
        self.process2 = subprocess.Popen(["bash"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        exit = False
        
        #start threads (stdout and stderror monitor)
        threading.Thread(target=self.read_stdout_1).start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.read_stderror_1).start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.read_stdout_2).start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.read_stderror_2).start()
        
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self.ws, bg="#777474")
        self.frame2.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(100,100), pady=(10, 10), sticky="W")
        
        #Start button
        self.btnVerify = Button(self.ws, text='Start', command=self.ButtonClick)
        self.btnVerify.grid(row=5, columnspan=3, pady=10)
        
        #output text area
        self.logArea = tkst.ScrolledText(self.ws, wrap= tk.WORD, width=80, height=20, name="logArea")
        self.logArea.grid(padx=(100,100), pady=(10, 10) ,row=10, sticky="W")


    def read_stdout_1(self):
        while not exit:
            msg = self.process1.stdout.readline()
            self.logArea.insert(INSERT, "process_1 logging start")
            self.logArea.insert(INSERT, msg.decode())
            self.logArea.insert(END, "\n logging end")
            
    def read_stderror_1(self):
        while not exit:
            msg = self.process1.stderr.readline()
            self.logArea.insert(INSERT, "Error")
            self.logArea.insert(INSERT, msg.decode())
            self.logArea.insert(END, "\n Error end")


    def read_stdout_2(self):
        while not exit:
            msg = self.process2.stdout.readline()
            self.logArea.insert(INSERT, "process_2 logging start")
            self.logArea.insert(INSERT, msg.decode())
            self.logArea.insert(END, "\logging end")

            
    def read_stderror_2(self):
        while not exit:
            msg = self.process2.stderr.readline()
            self.logArea.insert(INSERT, "Error")
            self.logArea.insert(INSERT, msg.decode())
            self.logArea.insert(END, "\n Error end")


    def ButtonClick(self):
        print("Button clicked")
        
        #set flag to 1
        self.flag = 1
        
        while not exit:
            if self.flag == 1:
                print("Case 1")
                self.process1.stdin.write(r'python C:\path\test1.py'.encode())
                self.process1.stdin.flush()
                self.flag = 2
                
            elif self.flag == 2:
                print("Case 2")
                self.process1.stdin.write(r'python C:\path\test2.py'.encode())
                self.process1.stdin.flush()
                self.flag = 3
            
            elif self.flag == 3:
                print("Case 3")
                self.process2.stdin.write(r'python C:\path\test3.py'.encode())
                self.process2.stdin.flush()
                self.flag = 4
           
            elif self.flag == 4:
                print("Case 3")
                self.process2.stdin.write(r'python C:\path\test4.py'.encode())
                self.process2.stdin.flush()
                self.flag = 5
                
            else:
                break


    def run(self):
        self.ws.title('Test Script')
        self.ws.mainloop() 
        
validator = TKValidator()
validator.run()
```

But after exectuing this script, I can see only the output like

```
Button clicked
```

I want to run the while loop one by one but it is not working. Can you please suggest, what is the problem here and how can I fix this to work as I expected ?

Comment: independently of whatever is going wrong here, are you trying to reimplement [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) ?

Comment: what is `while not exit` supposed to do?  No variable `exit` is bound in scope, and non exists in enclosing scope either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer here is this line:

```py
while not exit:
```

The value of `exit` here is always `True`.  Try printing exit to find out what it actually is:

```py
print(exit, bool(exit))
while not exit:
```

Incidentally `exit` was a bad variable name for this reason.

The longer answer is: why are you doing things this way?  As far as I can tell (I admit I only skimmed the code and the control flow manages to be sufficiently convoluted that I'm not sure I followed it) your requirements are:

- when a button is clicked, two scripts should be launched
- when they are finished (or whilst running?), their outputs should be printed to the textarea

There is no reason to mess about with starting shells, feeding to their stdin, polling their stdout, etc, for any of this.  Just launch a process, join it and drop the output into the textarea or poll it whist running and output to the textarea.  If you want to output from two subprocesses at once you need deconfliction logic: probably a queue of some description.

If you need to interact with the scripts I *strongly* recommend you use [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html).

Comment: I am using this script it in windows system. So "pexpect" will not work. I tried "wexpect" in windows, but how to run a GIT bash using wexpect.spawn  method? Can you suggest some example to control the bash and run a python script over the bash ?

Comment: You *can* use pexpect on windows: you just can't use spawn.  Which is normally fine (you can use PopenSpawn, which works the same way as your attempt, so it's probably fine).  That said I've had another look at your code and I don't know what you're trying to do.  Why are you trying to launch bash and then get it to launch python?  If you don't need to interact with your scripts either 1. run them directly (`run["\\path\\to\\python.exe", "\\path\\to\\script.py"]) or 2. use `bash -c` to launch bash to launch the script (but I'm not sure why you'd do this).

Comment: bash is just an interactive cli program FWIW. It happens to be optimised for running other programs, but interacting with it is no different from anything else.  'Git bash' is just a version of bash shipped with git for windows (which is indeed very useful) which loads up IIRC inside a windows 'console' window.